# Is "times" really a plural noun?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the question [What part of speech are "plus", "times", and "minus"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138182/what-part-of-speech-are-plus-times-and-minus), we discover that *plus* is a preposition, and are left to assume that so is *times*, in phrases such as "five times six".

That seems to make sense to me.

However, I checked [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time#time__34), and it states that *times* is a plural noun.

Not to be won over by the lesser sibling, I checked the OED.com and found, to my surprise, the same answer:

> A. n. ...
>   II. A point of time; a moment in time; a space of time considered without reference to its duration; an occasion, an instance. ...
>   19. In pl. Preceded by a number (in words or figures). ...
>   b. Followed by a number or an expression of quantity: expressing the multiplication of this by the preceding number.
>   <sub>Conventionally represented by the multiplication sign: 4 × 5 is read as ‘four times five’.</sub>

How is *times*, in e.g. "Four times five is twenty.", considered a noun?

Comment: *Times* doesn't go with *plus* and *minus*. *Multiplied by* and *divided by* do.

Comment: *Multiplied by* means *times*. I think the equivalent for *divided by* would be *over*. So, yes, it does "go with" *plus* and *minus*.

Comment: Considering that you can say "I am timesing four by five", "four was timesed by five" *times* must be at least sometimes a verb. Of course it's very awkward to pin any word class on *times*, but calling it a noun is nonsensical. I wouldn't say this is at all a nonstandard usage. In "four times five is twenty" I'd call *times* a stative verb, which is why it appears uninflected.

Answer (score 14):

I think it depends on how you perceive the word. For example, Merriam-Webster defines [**times**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/times) as a **preposition** meaning:

> multiplied by: '*three times two is six*'

in the same way it defines [**minus**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minus):

> [*preposition*] used to indicate that one number or amount is being subtracted from
>   another

All 5 other dictionaries I can check now, Wiktionary, Collins Online Dictionary, American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language Fifth Edition (2011), Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary © 2010, Dictionary.com define it as a **preposition**.

If *times* is classified as a (plural) *noun*, *three times two* would be a three-word compound noun where the first and second noun usually function as a *noun adjunct* which modifies the last noun as in "health care center" or "Obama Byden administration". The role of the noun *times* in the middle is not very clear.

However, if *times* is classified as a preposition, *times two* in "three times two" will be a prepositional phrase which can post-modify the noun *three*.

> Three *times* two is six. Three *minus* two is one.
>   The book *on* the table
>   is mine. The book *under* the table is yours.

We can notice that the *times/minus two* works in the same way as *on/under the table* as a **post-modifying prepositional phrase**. Times seems to be closer to a *preposition* than a *noun*.

Comment: The way I perceive it, is that when you talk about, say, an event, you'd say :"It happened three times". In this case, would you analyze "times" as a preposition? The event i is "happening/multiplied" by 3 occasions. I think, but I've got no source for that, hence a comment, that's why "times" is considered a noun. "2 times 3" is a way of saying  "2,(happening) 3 times". It'd be awkward to say, and people instead use 2 Times 3. Putting the noun before the numeral to avoid confusion. Think about this: "how many times did you multiply it by?"  You cannot "many" anything but a noun.

Comment: @P.Obertelli I am in the middle of editing my post, but since you asked. If you contrast "the book **on** the table is mine" and "the book **under** the table is yours", you see the prepositional phrase is post-modifying the noun *book*. I think *times* and *minus* in "2 times/minus 2"  work in the same way.

Comment: Is *times* in '1 times 2 is 2' OK?

Comment: @haha *times* is not a verb. One times one is one.

Comment: Thanks, I though it was a noun.

Comment: @haha My pleasure. Part of Speech is tricky and controversial as you have noticed in my question about "NOW". :-)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. [That](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291007/is-now-a-preposition) was an interesting question.

Comment: @rathony, in fact 'times' in this sense is a verb, at least in British English. The OED lists it as such (see my answer below). Although - in Merriam Webster,an American Dictionary, does indeed list it as a preposition. The joys of English!

Comment: Is 'take' a verb in 'five take two is three'? I think you're on a sticky wicket with '_times_ is not a verb'. As @Peter Shor says, 'mathematical operations _minus, plus, times_ have a different syntax than most of English ... None of the traditional parts of speech fits them perfectly.' So if we claim 'times is not a verb', we should balance this with 'times is not a preposition / noun / adverb ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I read the below answer posted by Jascol and I am not convinced. Is it a transitive verb or intransitive verb? If you want to prove that times could be a verb, please go ahead and prove it yourself.

Comment: If you think of the arrow diagram often used to illustrate a transformation rather than a static relation, it may well have x 2 written over the arrow. It could equally well have 'double' written to describe the operation. For x 5, 'increase scale factor 5'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Most of diagrams and charts use words or phrases part of which is elided or abbreviated. It is not a good example to prove times is a verb. Head noun is elided in **x 2**. It is not different from **2 (or whatever) x 2**.

Comment: I was hoping you'd realise that that was just an indicator to the semantics involved, to pinpoint the verbal flavour involved. For the parallel 'three take one is two', I haven't found any dictionary claiming that 'take' is a preposition, and I'd doubt you could. Notice that I'm not claiming that 'verb' is the correct word class here, but that there are problems with all attempts at a classical classification. // A complication is that the process of subtraction covers both the transformation of reduction, and the comparison by differencing (arguably less 'verby').

Comment: You're _choosing_ when you can choose to label relict forms as still extant. Two counted three times is six. // 'Three take one is two' is extremely common in BrE. And surely you wouldn't jib at 'Two add one is three'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I added "Times seems to be closer to preposition than noun". If you don't like it, please go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Peter Shor's 'None of the traditional parts of speech fits them perfectly' is correct and his 'but in my opinion preposition comes closest' a good working hypothesis (once the confusion about the different senses OP should avoid on ELU has been dealt with).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I respectfully disagree with you. **I think it depends on how you perceive the word.** is the first sentence I used in my post. Shall we stop now?

Comment: This is from the previous post: 'As you will have observed by now, identifying the "part of speech" of a particular word tells you nothing about the grammar, and is always fraught with disagreement, because the usual list of the Classical Eight was developed at about the same time as the Crusades for a different language, and suits modern English somewhat worse than English spelling does. So, whatever you decide, nothing useful has been discovered. However, it may please your teacher. – @John Lawler'

Comment: [Is “now” a “preposition”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291007/is-now-a-preposition) is the question I asked. I hope you upvoted it. There is no harm in trying to identify and classify part of speech. It is related with English Language and its Usage. More than 99% of the words belong to traditional and grammatical part of speech. If you are talking about the remaining 1% or less, I can't agree with John Lawler more.

Comment: Don't forget that the word *by* can be substituted for *times* in those cases when it functions as a preposition. "2 *by* 2 is 4."

Comment: @Tim Ward Obviously from 'two multiplied by two', but that doesn't describe its function in the deleted form (an ex-preposition?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is it? I thought it odd, because when I was young, my mother used to say things like that, but I was only familiar with the "2 by 4" meaning a cut of wood... I think there's more to this linguistically than merely a reduction or omission of a word that explicates its function. Of course my mom knew I didn't understand exactly what she was saying and was trying to get me thinking. She eventually just said it was the same thing as 2 times 4. But I wondered about that ever since...

Comment: I fail to see how 'Is “now” a “preposition”? is the question I asked.' is relevant; 'the previous post' refers to OP's linked 'What part of speech are "plus", "times", and "minus"'.

Comment: @TimWard I've always been under the impression that 2 by 4 comes from multiplication being understood as a calculation of area. 2 inches by 4 inches is 8 square inches. 2 by 4 is 8.

Comment: @DCShannon yes, that's exactly my point. The 'by' there also functions as multiplication, like 'times'. And my mom wasn't talking about area; she was just using 'by' instead of 'times'. In fact, she was reading the math homework I had and substituting 'by' where the 'x' for 'times' was written in the problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35623/discussion-on-answer-by-rathony-is-times-really-a-plural-noun).

Answer (score 6):

The Oxford Dictionaries define [minus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minus) as a preposition, which is inconsistent with their definition of *times* as a noun.

The mathematical operations *minus, plus, times* have a different syntax than most of English, and this apparently confuses grammarians. None of the traditional parts of speech fits them perfectly, but in my opinion *preposition* comes closest.

Comment: You're saying Oxford is wrong???

Comment: @HotLicks One should never trust a dictionary for parts of speech. Better to go to a reputable grammar, which is where the dictionaries get their parts of speech from - with a fifty year time lag.

Comment: @Hot Licks I'll certainly say that ODO is wrong here.

Comment: I'd argue that, as 'add/plus', 'minus/subtract/take', and 'times' all signify operations, they are at least equally close to verbs. But I agree that they are not central members of traditional word classes (I'd go further and say they're not members of traditional word classes) and they're certainly not nouns in the a * b = c usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Add", "subtract", and "multiply" are verbs.  Sometimes people use "times" as if it were "multiply" ("Times that number by ten") but it is nonstandard usage.  However, "plus", "minus", and "times" (standard usage) do not describe actions.

Comment: @Monty Harder If you look through this thread, you will see that I've already said 'Sometimes people use "times" as if it were "multiply" ("Times that number by ten") but that does not make it standard usage.' or words to that effect. We're discussing the POS of 'times' in the standard usage 'Two times three equals six'. As Peter says, 'None of the traditional parts of speech fits [times in this usage] perfectly'. Peter implies it might be best lumped with prepositions; Professor Lawler says that insisting on a POS (here) is divisive and unhelpful.

Comment: Their saying times is a noun is *different from* plus and minus; it's not *inconsistent with* them, because they're asserting that it *is* different and was derived differently. In a sense they're even right, although I'd say that they're preserving a distinction that's pretty well dead by now.

Comment: (What they're asserting is that "three times two" is equivalent to "two, three times", and that "times" in that phrase serves the same function as in "what I say three times is true".)

Comment: @HotLicks - Sarcasm doesn't come off so well on the internet ;)

Comment: @Mazura -- ??? I'm never sarcastic!

Answer (score 6):

The phrase **four times five** means **five, four times** i.e. **five, five, five, five**.

In this context, I think the meaning of it is similar to the meaning of times in "Once, twice, three times a lady".  It's basically stating four occurrences of **five**, which, when totaled, equal twenty.

In the arithmetic, it's used idiomatically to describe multiplication.  The fact that it looks similar in construction to **four plus five** is coincidental.

By this reasoning, **times** is a plural noun in the phrase **four times** which functions as an adjective describing the amount of **fives**.

Comment: With your reasoning, "one times five" would be incorrect, right?

Comment: @MrLister That would appear to be the case.

Comment: At first glance, it seems at least plausible that this interpretation ("five, four times") explains the _origin_ of this meaning of the word "times". But meanings and parts of speech change over time, and Mr Lister's example strongly implies that even if the word "times" in "four times five" was once a plural noun, it no longer is.

Answer (score 5):

*The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (By Bas Aarts, Sylvia Chalker, Edmund Weiner) defines *times* as a ***marginal preposition*** (along with *less, minus* and *plus*).

> marginal preposition: a preposition that shares one or more characteristics with other word classes. For example, many marginal prepositions share certain features with verbs or adjectives.
>
> Among the marginal prepositions are *less, minus, plus* and *times*.
>
> - What's five *times* six?
> - He arrived *minus* a ticket.

Comment: Sounds like a definition that is grasping at straws ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii: or covering all the bases. It is a grammar term and this is not the only source mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the second definition.  They are not talking about multiplying numbers, as in "eight times five equals forty". They are talking about expressing the number of iterations you performed an actions, as in "I ran around the track eight times".

Comment: No, OP didn't misinterpret. There are examples like "<number> times <number>" under that definition. The definition has this subnote also: "Conventionally represented by the multiplication sign: 4 × 5 is read as ‘four times five’."

Comment: I think that is a bad example on the oxford dictionaries part, as the rest of the examples they give are like mine.  Also, don't know where OP got "Conventionally represented by the multiplication sign: 4 × 5 is read as ‘four times five’." but I can't find that anywhere on the linked page

Comment: OP mentioned that it is from *OED.com*. It is not accessible by public, you need subscription. Also, the sense of "times" you are talking about is different. OP didn't say anything about it.

Comment: Yes he did.  "19. In pl. Preceded by a number (in words or figures)"

Comment: You need to know how OED works. It is the general parent definition of subdefinitions. It doesn't say or prove much by itself and there can't be specific examples for that general parent definition.

Comment: @Kevin it's part b. below that that completes the definition.

Comment: Alright this damn thing is messing with my brain.  It's like a verb, noun and preposition at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Let's examine some sentences similar to "Four times five is twenty.":

> "Four plus five is nine."
>
> "Four and five are nine."

In the latter sentence, "and" is clearly a conjunction.  I think there is a good case to be made that "plus", and "times" are conjunctions, (as the statement is not about either four or five individually, but about a combination of them) with "minus" and "divided by" having progressively less of a conjunctive character and more of a noun-modified-by-prepositional-phrase (or participle) flavor:

> "Five from nine is four"
>
> "Nine minus five is four"
>
> "Twenty divided by five is four"

Higher-order mathematical operations seem even more solidly in the latter camp:

> "Four squared is sixteen"  (participle "squared")
>
> "Four raised to the fifth power is 1,024." (participle modified by prepositional phrase)
>
> "Four to the fifth power is 1,024." (prepositional phrase)

Comment: Notice that in "four and five are nine" you use "are" vs "is".  The sentence structure is entirely different.  It's equivalent to saying "Sue and Fred are a couple".

Comment: @HotLicks "Is" and "are" are both forms of "be". I've certainly heard people say "four and five is nine"; I just happen to prefer the plural form.

Answer (score -1):

I think to label plus and minus (and times) as prepositions is incompetence of dictionaries. As "minus" is a Latin comparative it is principally an adjective form which was adopted in mathematics as an operation sign. The same is true for "plus".  Dictionaries may declare minus and plus are prepositions, but actually it is nonsense to label mathematical operation signs as prepositions.

50 minus 10 means 50 diminished by 10. I can't see what "diminished by" has to do with a preposition.

"times" can be a normal plural as in "in olden times" and it can be an operation sign in mathematics, also called operator in mathematical terminology.
50 times 10 is/equals 500 - here times means "multiplied by", and I would hardly call that a preposition.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. The question is about nouns.

Comment: No. The question is about, times, plus and minus.

Answer (score -1):

That dictionary entry is wrong. I assume it was an oversight.

When "times" is used to represent multiplication it's a preposition, as has been adequately explained by several of these answers, and as it is listed in most dictionaries.

"Times" is a plural noun when used in a different context:

- These are strange times.
- How are your forty times?
- We had some good times.

Answer (score -2):

"Times" could definitely be a noun depending on context,
such as "*These are strange times we're living in.*" or
"*My times in the 5k have been improving due to my new speed intervals workout routine*."

Comment: Please re-read the question. This has nothing to do with what is actually being asked.

Comment: This has a lot to do with what is being asked, they just left out the logic connecting it. This is when times is a plural noun, not when it's used in multiplication.

Comment: Precisely, I demonstrated when it IS a plural noun, when used in multiplication, it is a verb.